# Keycode.return in update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I want to happen. By pressing 'Return' I only expect one if statement to carry out an action. The first play through is fine, but when the Startgame() function is called again, the first press of the 'Return' key activates both of the if statements. I am unsure why.

```
using UnityEngine;


  using System.Collections;

    public class NumberWizard : MonoBehaviour {

        int max;
        int min;
        int guess;

        bool playerSelectedRange = false;

        void StartGame()
        {
            max = 1000;
            min = 1;
            guess = 500;

            playerSelectedRange = false;

            print ("=======================");
            print("Welcome to number wizard");
            print ("The lowest number you can pick is 1. Would you like the maximum number to be 1000?");
            print ("Up = Higher, Down = Lower, Return = Happy with this number");
        }

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            StartGame();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

            if (playerSelectedRange == true) {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
                    min = guess;
                    NextGuess();
                }
                else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
                    max = guess;
                    NextGuess();
                }
                else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)){
                    print("I won");
                    StartGame();
                }
            }

            if (playerSelectedRange == false)
            {   
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                {
                    max = max + 100;
                    MaxRange();
                }
                else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
                    max = max - 100;
                    MaxRange();
                }
                else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)){
                    print ("Lets play!!!");
                    print ("Choose a number between 1 and " + max);
                    max = max + 1;
                    NextGuess();
                    playerSelectedRange = true;
                }
            }


        }

        void NextGuess()
        {
            guess = (max+min)/2;
            print ("Is your number higher or lower than " + guess + "?");
            print ("Up arrow key for higher. Down arrow key for lower. Return key for Correct");
        }



        void MaxRange()
        {
            print ("Do you want it to be " + max + "?");
            print ("Up = higher, down = lower, return = Just right");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        if (playerSelectedRange == true) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
                min = guess;
                NextGuess();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
                max = guess;
                NextGuess();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)){
                print("I won");
                StartGame();
            }
        }else 
        {   
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                max = max + 100;
                MaxRange();
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
                max = max - 100;
                MaxRange();
            }
            else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)){
                print ("Lets play!!!");
                print ("Choose a number between 1 and " + max);
                max = max + 1;
                NextGuess();
                playerSelectedRange = true;
            }
        }
```

Seems like should do the trick. The problem with yours is, you're saying `if(playerSelectedRange)...` and then you invoke `StartGame` which sets `playerSelectedRange` to false and then the other if statement you have gets executed. This ensures it only gets executed once.

Comment: What throws me is that it is still true at the time of the keypress

Comment: Right, but code executes based on lines. So you execute code when it's pressed, which then changes the value, and then you do another if statement when the value was changed.

Comment: My solution won't check the second if statement you have after it's been pressed. I think this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is clear now. I understand. Thanks